#  .append causing IE error

Tags: jquery, append

I have the following code, which works fine in FF, but the `.append()` function s cauding an error in IE. Is anyone able to tell me if there is anything wrong with my code, or if this is an IE problem?

The purpose is to add a hidden field to a form (will be different depending on what the user clicks), and I then submit the form.

```
$(function(){

    $('a.js-make-profile-image').click(function(){
        $('.append-here').append('<input type="hidden" name="action-type" value="profile-image" />');
        document.forms['attachment-action-form'].submit();
    });

});
```

The IE debugger is giving the error `Unexpected call to method or property access`, and this text is being hightlighted within jQuery by the debugger - `this.nodeType===1&&this.appendChild(a)`.

Comment: Are you supposed to have that extra semicolon after click(function(){; <---

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: It looks like it should work. I know that IE can have problem if the rest of the DOM is currupt, maybe some other tag is opened? If you just try .append("test") does it work? Which of the lines causing you problem?

Comment: @NathanFitzgerald: That is superflous, but won't cause a problem.

Comment: @NathanFitzgerald - Well spotterd, but still getting an error. As for a message - Unexpected call to method or property access (and this text is being hightlighted within jQuery by the debugger - `this.nodeType===1&&this.appendChild(a)`).

Comment: Instead of `document.forms['attachment-action-form'].submit();`, try `document.forms[0].submit();` assuming you have just the one form on the page.

Comment: @j08691 - Thanks, but it's not that line that is causing an issue - even with it removed the error still occurs.

Comment: do you have a div with class 'append-here'? It looks like the div Id to me. can you try $('#append-here')?

Comment: @DavidGard - Just wanted to try something with that suggestion. Can you post the HTML that you're using and any other JavaScript?

Comment: Which version of IE is it failing on?  Is "append-here" a div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) you have an extra `;`

```
$('a.js-make-profile-image').click(function(){;
```

at the end of this line.
if this don't solve your problem please update your question with the error reported by IE

2) I think you could also have a conflict due to the value of your `name` attribute.

You have both a `type` attribute and `name="type"`:
since you can usually access to a DOM element also via *`<element>.<name>`* what exactly `<input>.type` should returns? The element `type` attribute value or a reference to the input element into the DOM?

so try to change the `name` attribute value

3) if nothing has changed yet just try to change the code

```
$('.append-here').append('<input type="hidden" name="type" 
                           value="profile-image" />');
```

in

```
$('<input />').attr({
    "type"  : "hidden",
    "name"  : "action-type",
    "value" : "profile-image"
}).appendTo($('.append-here'));
```

and, as you discovered, be sure that the element `append-here` is not an empty element.

Comment: Good spot, but that sadly is not causing the issue. As for a message - Unexpected call to method or property access (and this text is being hightlighted within jQuery by the debugger - `this.nodeType===1&&this.appendChild(a)`).

Comment: Good thought, I've changed "type" to "action-type", but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Well, it was initially a sad face result, but I have now sorted it. It was happening because my class `append-here` was in an <input />, whcih I guess IE doesn't like. Added `<div class="append-here"></div>` and all now seems right with the world. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavidGard - You were attempting to append an input element _within_ another input element?

Comment: @DavidGard How bizarre... you should get an error everywhere, not only on IE

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - I guess the other browsers are just better!

Comment: @DavidGard in this specific case I'd prefer to get an error as IE does.

Answer (score 2):

The only way i can duplicate this error is using IE8 and appending the hidden field to something daft like an image tag.

Could you check that '.append-here' is a div?  If you could paste the html that would help and which version of IE is it failing on?

Comment: It wasn't a div that I was attempting to append, I was unaware that it had to be. The problem is now solved. Thanks.