# Object expected error in IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have four php pages:

1. `header.php`
2. `demo1.php`
3. `demo2.php`
4. `demo3.php`

I am including `header.php` in every page i.e `demo1.php`, `demo2.php` and `demo3.php`. I included common JavaScript required for `demo1.php`, `demo2.php` and `demo3.php` in `header.php`.

`header.php` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
     $("#btn1").click(function(){
       console.log("btn1 clicked");
      });
     $("#btn2").click(function(){
      console.log("btn2 clicked");
     });

});
</script>
```

`btn1` and `btn2` elements are not declared in `header.php`, but they are declared in included pages like `demo1.php`, `demo2.php` and `demo3.php`.

`demo1.php` code:

```
 <?php include "header.php";?>
 <input type="button" id="btn1" value="check"/>
 <input type="button" id="btn2" value="check"/>
```

This `demo1.php` page works in all browsers except in IE.

In IE it showing error **Object expected** at `$("btn1").click(function(){});`.

Can any one help me achieving this problem?

Comment: Did you have the console open? If the console isn't open, IE will fail on console.log

Comment: As @KevinB said there is no console object available unless you open the developer tools.. So try using alert instead of console.log  or instantiate the console object on your page

Comment: for console i am using this code `if(!window.console){console.log("btn1 clicked");}`

Comment: I guess the console is open, otherwise you can't notice the error.

Comment: Yeah that's what i expected, i didn't think console was the problem because it doesn't match the error that is happening. does removing `type="text/javascript" language="javascript"` make any difference?

Comment: ya i tried with removing `type="text/javascript" laguage="javascript"` but it is showing same error

Comment: Is jQuery loaded correctly? Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: jquery loaded correctly except that code remaining jquery code is working fine

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Jb9fY/ @pimvdb I've added the jQuery on the left, otherwise I think it's the same as your example.

Comment: I wrote javascript in header.php page and this header.php page is included in demo1.php page, demo1.php contains actual DOM elements i.e `<input type="button" value="check" id="btn1">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have an [implicit semicolon or append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230567/) at this line:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
```

It could also be an issue caused by the [base element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234172/).